# What is significance getDml code below in Salesforce Test code

Tags: salesforce, dml

Can anyone explain me  significance getDml code below in Salesforce Test code

```
  @isTest static void TestContactWithInvalidNameNotInserted(){

    String inputLastName = 'INVALIDNAME';
    Contact newcontact = new Contact(LastName=inputLastName);

    Test.startTest();
    try{
        insert newcontact;
    }
    catch(DmlException dmlEx){
        String expectedMessage = 'The Last Name' +newcontact.LastName+'is not allowed for DML';
        System.assertEquals(expectedMessage, dmlEx.getDmlMessage(0));
    }
    Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance the catch block only catches exceptions of type DmlException. getDmlMessage() is how you can get the message property of the exception.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: but what if i provide getDmlMessage(1) instead of getDmlMessage(0),what is the difference between index 0 and 1?

Comment: The integer passed in represents the index of the record with the error. If you insert a list of 10 SObjects, index 0-9 can be used to see if an error occurred on that record.